# Finding the point c guaranteed by Rolle's Theorem on the interval [a,b].

Tags: real-analysis

Question: Suppose that a<b and define a function f by $f(x) = (x-a)^2(x-b)^4$. Find the point c guaranteed by Rolle's Theorem on the interval [a,b].

This is my proof so far:

Given $f(x) = (x-a)^2(x-b)^4$ on [a,b]. Then f(a)= 0 and f(b) = 0 $\Rightarrow$f(a) = f(b).
Also, $f'(x) = 2(x-a)(x-b)^4+4(x-a)^2(x-b)^3$ exists for all $x \in (a,b)$ so f(x) is differentiable on (a,b). Thus f(x) is continuous as well. Then by applying Rolle's Theorem, there exists a $c\in (a,b)$ such that $f'(c)=0$. So,

$2(c-a)(c-b)^4+4(c-a)^2(c-b)^3 = 0$

$\Rightarrow 2(c-a)(c-b)^3(c-b+2c-2a) = 0 $

$\Rightarrow 2(c-a)(c-b)^3(3c-b-2a) = 0 $

This is where I am stuck. I know that I need to solve for c. I have seen answers that give

$c =a,b $ so $ (b+2a)/3 $ but I can't seem to get this work out.

Answer (score 1):

We have $f(x) = (x-a)^2(x-b)^4$ and, as you've noted,
$$f^\prime(x) = 2(x-a)(x-b)^4 + 4(x-a)^2(x-b)^3.$$
So, we want to solve
$$0 = 2(c-a)(c-b)^3((c-b) + 2(c-a)) = 2(c-a)(c-b)^3(3c-2a-b).$$
You got to here and this is almost the finish line. You just need to notice that the LHS is $0$. This means that $(c-a)=0$, $(c-b)^3=0$ or $3c-2a-b=0$.

Recall that the $c$ given by Rolle's theorem is in $(a,b)$. This means that we want $a<c<b$ and so
$$3c = 2a+b \text{ or } c=\frac{1}{3}(2a+b).$$